# When I tap the first cell in my tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not triggered

Tags: iphone, cell, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When I tap the first cell in my tableview `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not triggered...  Has anyone seem this and/or have any clue as to why this happens?  All the other cells in my table work just fine and I put a breakpoint in my code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the app does not go into that code if the first cell is tapped but will go into the code if the any other cell is tapped.
Here is some code:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = 0;
    return row;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row == 0)
        return nil;

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    //NSString *rowValue = [poolListData objectAtIndex:row];

    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = [lastIndexPathForPoolList row];

    if (newRow != oldRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPathForPoolList]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        lastIndexPathForPoolList = indexPath;   
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)tableViewForDelete:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [poolListData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewtableViewForDelete:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *DeleteMeCellIdentifier = @"DeleteMeCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DeleteMeCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:DeleteMeCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.text = [self.poolListData objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    [self.poolListData removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Thank you for your time and any help you can give me!

Comment: Sorry for the mess...I can not seem to get the code to paste in right.

Comment: corrected that for you. Where is lastindexpathforpoollist initializerd?

Comment: did you setup the tableview.delegate ?

Comment: I have lastIndexPathForPoolList in the delegate
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPathForPoolList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPathForPoolList;

But i did not initialize it (oops)

Comment: where would be the best place to initialize lastIndexPathForPoolList?

Comment: A couple of comments - why override "willSelect" - you aren't doing anything there. Also your method for changing the accessory view is wrong. You should have didSelect set some sort of variable, and send the tableView the reloadDate message. cellForRowAtIndexPath should read that variable and and set the cell's accessoryView accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your return nil in willSelectRowForIndexPath for the first row. This will prevent the row from being selected.

Comment: Getting there!!! I took that out and now i can select the first row but only after i select any other row first!! Thank you!!